# Changing contrast with ImageJ plugin

Tags: java, imagej, contrast

The objective of the plugin is to take a slice from a stack and then create a new stack with multiple images of the same slice but with different contrasts.

I wrote a for loop, but the results are not what I intended. The new stack is created but it's always the same image in every slice.
What am I missing here?

```
public void run(ImageProcessor ip) {
    ImageProcessor ip2 = ip.duplicate();
    ImageStack nstack = new ImageStack(stack.getWidth(),stack.getHeight());
    ip2.snapshot();
        for(int i=0; i<256; i=i+10){
        ip2.setMinAndMax(0,i);
        nstack.addSlice("Contrast "+i, ip2);
        ip2.reset();
        }

    ImagePlus imp2= new ImagePlus("teste", nstack);
    imp2.show();
    }}
```

Comment: The addSlice method only updates the min and max [the first time it's called](https://github.com/imagej/ImageJA/blob/v1.49q/src/main/java/ij/ImageStack.java#L107-111) (if there are no other slices) so your settings aren't being preserved. I'm not sure how to do what you want though... you may have better luck on the [ImageJ Mailing list](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/list.html).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Michael Schmid on the [ImageJ mailing list](http://imagej.1557.x6.nabble.com/Contrast-PlugIn-tp5012471p5012508.html),

> the Brightness & Contrast settings determine how the data are
>   displayed, they do not affect the actual data

In case of 8-bit images, you can use the `applyLut()` method of the [`ByteProcessor` class](http://javadoc.imagej.net/ImageJ1/index.html?ij/process/ByteProcessor.html) after setting the contrast:

```
ip2.setMinAndMax(0,i);
ip2.applyLut();
```